Antd Auto-scrolled Dropdown in React
I am trying to create an automatically scrolled Dropdown using antd@5.16.0.
I want to have the dropdown list always scrolled to the end on every mouse hover.
This is an example of what I want to achieve.
I found this from another stack overflow question, but it is using another component Drawer with an older version of antd, which is antd@4.7.0.
As you can see from my code, the dropdown list doesn't scroll till the end of hover.
It only scrolls when the mouse leaves the Dropdown component.
The list also will not scroll till the end after a new item is added to the list (by clicking the Add button).
How to achieve the same auto-scrolled effect while keeping the same antd@5.16.0 version?

Edit:
I used the answer from this Github issue. Works great.

It doesn't work in your case because there's no node render for the first time when you hover over button. Second you only want to scroll when dropdown opens not on close. You can wrap the scrollTo code in setTimeout without any timeout and only scroll when dropdown opens. Here's the complete working code
import { DownOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Button, Dropdown, Space } from 'antd';
import { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
    const [logItems, setLogItems] = useState([
        { label: `[${new Date().toLocaleString()}] Clicking me will not close the menu.`, key: 1 },
        { label: `[${new Date().toLocaleString()}] Clicking me will not close the menu.`, key: 2 },
        { label: `[${new Date().toLocaleString()}] Clicking me will not close the menu.`, key: 3 },
        { label: `[${new Date().toLocaleString()}] Clicking me will not close the menu.`, key: 4 }
    ]);

    const items = logItems.length > 0 ? [...logItems] : [{ label: 'No log', key: '0' }];

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        setLogItems((prevLogItems) => {
            return [
                { label: `[${new Date().toLocaleString()}] Clicking me will not close the menu.`, key: prevLogItems.length + 1 },
                ...prevLogItems
            ];
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Button type='primary' onClick={handleClick}>
                Add
            </Button>
            <Dropdown
                overlayClassName='custom-dropdown-menu'
                overlayStyle={{ maxHeight: 80, overflow: 'auto' }}
                menu={{
                    items,
                    selectable: false,
                    selectedKeys: [`${items[items.length - 1].key}`]
                }}
                onOpenChange={(open) => {
                    if (open) {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            document.body.querySelector('.custom-dropdown-menu')?.scrollTo(0, 9999);
                        });
                    }
                }}
            >
                <Space>
                    Hover me
                    <DownOutlined />
                </Space>
            </Dropdown>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;

